# SVG Preloader with CSS animation that randomizes on each page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So i made a svg logo preloader, made some css animations for it also. But my main problem is how do i make the preloader load different animation on refresh/new page loading using javascript. Like for example on one page loading the logo should use the bounce animation and upon a page refreh or on another tab opening the preloader to use the rotate animation i made, etc.

```js
var strings = [
  'animation1.',
    'animation2.',
    'animation3.'
];

var rand = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
document.getElementById('loading-animation').innerHTML = rand;
```

```css
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.svg {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.animation1 {
  just an example
}

.animation2 {
  just an example
}

.animation2 {
  just an example
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div id='loading-animation' class='loading-animation'>Processing</div>
     <svg>just an example svg in inserted in the html, no external src link to it</svg>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that .innerHTML shouldn't be there since the javascript file will be external linked in the head section. And i know i haven't linked all of the codes used just because it's to much code to paste here so i made a mini example, hope i can make myself understood. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to randomly apply a css class to the loader that is in the array?

Comment: Think that could work also, but seems kinda complicated, but if you can help out with an example i would appreciate it alot. But on a the subjectm, i was thinking more like using js to make random animation selection from the css animation file, like applying one animation on each page " refresh/loading " from the animations in css. Just one at a time. I'm pretty sure your solution could work also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to randomly assign a CSS class to the element you want to animate. Here is an example.

```js
var animationClasses = [
  'animation1',
  'animation2',
  'animation3'
];

var choosenAnimation = animationClasses[~~(Math.random() * animationClasses.length)];

document.getElementById('elementToAnimate').classList.add(choosenAnimation);
```

```css
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fly-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

.animation1 {
  width: fit-content;
  animation: grow 1s;
}

.animation2 {
  animation: fade 1s;
}

.animation3 {
  animation: fly-down 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="elementToAnimate">This will get a random animation</div>
```

A random class in the array `animationClasses` is assigned to `elementToAnimate`. Each class contains CSS for a different animation, allowing for a random animation each time.